# Why Standard Compression Scheme for Unicode sample code not work?

Tags: unicode, compression

I'm tring to learn SCSU 
[http://unicode.org/reports/tr6](http://unicode.org/reports/tr6/)
but when I try [Java sample code](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/PROGRAMS/SCSU/), the output always larger than input.
This is what I got:
I tried this example:

```
Öl fließt
```

they say the input:

```
Unicode code points (9 code points):
00D6 006C 0020 0066 006C 0069 0065 00DF 0074
```

and output is :

```
Compressed (9 bytes):
D6 6C 20 66 6C 69 65 DF 74
```

But what I got is:
Input:

```
famihug@hvn:/home/famihug/TestRoom/SCSU%xxd german.txt                      [0]
0000000: c396 6c20 666c 6965 c39f 7420 0a         ..l flie..t .
```

Output:

```
famihug@hvn:/home/famihug/TestRoom/SCSU%java CompressMain /compress german.txt
Compressed german.txt: 6 chars to german.csu 13 bytes. Ratio: 108%.

famihug@hvn:/home/famihug/TestRoom/SCSU%ls -lt german.*                     [0]
-rw-r--r-- 1 famihug famihug 13 2012-06-09 10:24 german.csu
-rw-r--r-- 1 famihug famihug 13 2012-06-08 01:04 german.txt

famihug@hvn:/home/famihug/TestRoom/SCSU%xxd german.csu                      [0]
0000000: 0fc3 966c 2066 6c69 65c3 9f74 20
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~
And this is when I tried Japanese sample:

```
famihug@hvn:/home/famihug/TestRoom/SCSU%wc -m jav.txt                       [0]
117 jav.txt
famihug@hvn:/home/famihug/TestRoom/SCSU%ls -lt jav.*                        [0]
-rw-r--r-- 1 famihug famihug 349 2012-06-08 01:13 jav.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 famihug famihug 405 2012-06-08 01:01 jav.csu
```

they said output is Compressed (178 bytes)

I use gedit/Vim to paste the sample plaintext to file. What did I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the sample encoder is expecting UTF-16 input, and you're giving it UTF-8.

This input: `c396 6c20 666c 6965 c39f 7420 0a` is `Öl fließt` in UTF-8, with a trailing space and newline.

What you're getting back is `0fc3 966c 2066 6c69 65c3 9f74 20`. The first `0f` is the `SCU` tag, which indicates that the rest of the bytes are big-endian UTF-16. The thing is, instead of the UTF-16 equivalents of your input string, the rest of the bytes are just the *exact same* bytes from the input (minus the newline), and those same bytes represent totally different characters between UTF-8 and UTF-16.

The output you're getting back seems to represent `쎖氠晬楥쎟琠`. Note that this is a 6 character long string, as `CompressMain` reported. You could run your compressed output back through `/expand` of the same class to confirm.

If you encode your input file in UTF-16, not UTF-8 you should get the output you're expecting.

Comment: 쎖氠晬楥쎟琠 is garbled output indeed: 2 (very rare) Korean syllables, 4 sinograms that are totally unrelated in meaning.

Comment: @John Flatness : thank you, it worked. But I want to ask you some addition question, coz it's hard to find one who worked with Unicode as you.
I saved my utf-8 file to utf-16, then use SCSU to compress it, after expand the compressed file, I got back my UTF-8 version no need addition action. Why?

Comment: You're sure you got UTF-8 back? It's *possible* but unlikely that code uses a different default encoding for input and output files.

Comment: Oop, my mistake, it's UTF-16, not UTF-8. Thanks for your help.

this is a little information about my question for anyone who need it : http://www.mail-archive.com/unicode@unicode.org/msg08104.html

as someone said on that link, I hope they will rewrite the document to help remove some misconceptions as I made.